# Удаление символов из строки java

Tags: java, строки

Есть список ненужных символов, допустим `String taboo = "1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+!№;%:?*/\\\"~`";`

И есть строка `String s = sc.nextLine();`

Как из вводимой строки удалить(заменить пробелами) все символы, которые есть в  списке `taboo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String taboo = "1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+!№;%:?*/\\\"~";
        String s = "Hello123World!?!.?!";

        for (char c : taboo.toCharArray()) {
            s = s.replace(c, ' ');
        }

        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: это будет с трудоёмкостью O(n^2).
лучше свой метод написать там будет замена символа по лукап- таблице:

char[] lookups = // заполняешь таблицу

public String replaceAll(String str, char[]lookups){
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i =0; i < str.size(); i++){
sb.append(lookups[str.charAt(i)];
}

Comment: Если это не высоконагруженный проект, то решение рабочее и простое. Я думаю, что Pavel Bobrov`у не критична производительность именно в этом проекте. Но Pavel Bobrov`у все же стоит изучить сложности алгоритмов и знать об этом, т.к. в реально нагруженном проекте без этих знаний никак.

Comment: стоит написать нормальные java.lang утилиты общего назначения. ты бы видел ЧТО пишут в реальных коммерческих проэктах.

Comment: user184868, Извини, не совсем понял твой ответ.

Comment: Спасибо.  В принципе, примерно это я и делал. Вот только до меня не дошло использовать foreach, благодарю

Comment: @Pavel Bobrov, советую обратить внимание на сложность алгоритма, в образовательных целях. Т.к. я не учитывал это, и постарался написать максимально простое и понятное решение.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться следующим методом  из библиотеки Apache Commons: [`StringUtils.replaceChars(String str, String searchChars, String replaceChar)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceChars-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

Comment: у них тоже 0(n^2):

Comment: у них тоже 0(n^2):
public static  String replace(String text, String searchString, String replacement, int max) {
....

      public static  String replaceChars(String str, String searchChars, String replaceChars) {

        int strLength = str.length();
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(strLength);
        for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++) { ~ 0(n)
            char ch = str.charAt(i);
            int index = searchChars.indexOf(ch);// внутри 0(m)
всего 0(n*m ~ n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы читаете текст построчно и этот текст достаточно длинный, то, возможно есть смысл сделать таким образом:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String taboo = "1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+!№;%:?*/\\\"~";
    Set<Character> symbols = taboo.chars().mapToObj(e->(char)e).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();


    String s = "Hello123World!?!.?!";
    result.append(delSymbols(s, symbols));


    System.out.println(result);
}

private static StringBuilder delSymbols(String nextString, Set<Character> symbols){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : nextString.toCharArray()) {
        if (!symbols.contains(ch)) sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.append("\r\n");
}
```

Две строки кода в средине метода main - это ваш цикл. В итоге на выходе вы получите объект StringBuilder в данном контексте именованный как result.

В этом случае приходится создавать дополнительную коллекцию типа сет, однако при большом объеме текста использование этой коллекции и StringBuilder должно окупиться и с точки зрения времени выполнения, и с точки зрения системных ресурсов.

Попробуйте протестировать на время в реальных условиях, выложите результат. Мне тоже интересно.

Answer (score -1):

```
taboo.replaceAll(было, стало);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, распишите ваше решение чуть более подробно

Comment: Что бы использовать replaceAll, необходимо знать регулярные выражения, смею предположить, что автор вопроса с ними не знаком и вопрос был не о регулярных выражениях. Но настоятельно рекомендую автору вопроса хотя бы ознакомится с regular expressions.

Comment: @Евгений, в данном конкретном случае нужно было именно сравнить 2 строки без использования регулярных выражений

Comment: Но, раз уж зашла речь о них. Может быть подскажете мне. Просто нигде информации такой я не нашел. `"(?<=\\G.{3})"` . Что сие за конструкция такая? Что вообще за \\G?