# Java обрезать текст по условию

Tags: java

Подскажите как достать только значение cn, без знаков = и ,

cn=Иванов Иван Иванович,ou=office,ou=Active,ou=Users,ou=nsk,dc=office,dc=ru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s = "cn=Иванов Иван Иванович,ou=office,ou=Active,ou=Users,ou=nsk,dc=office,dc=ru";
String onlyCnValue = s.split(",")[0].split("=")[1];
```

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек)

Answer (score 3):

```
String source = "cn=Иванов Иван Иванович,ou=office,ou=Active,ou=Users,ou=nsk,dc=office,dc=ru";
String result = source.substring(source.indexOf("cn=")+"cn=".length(), source.indexOf(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант по сложнее с регуляркой

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=cn=)[^,]*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("cn=Иванов Иван Иванович,ou=office,ou=Active,ou=Users,ou=nsk,dc=office,dc=ru");
        
if (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

[Результат](https://onecompiler.com/java/3wab9xr6j)

```
Иванов Иван Иванович
```

Comment: `[\\p{L}| ]` можно переписать и так: `[^,]`, поскольку запятая отделяет следующий блок с текстом :)

Answer (score 0):

.. а откуда? подозреваю из AD.
LdapAdmin скорее всего правильные пути подскажет http://www.ldapadmin.org/download/ldapadmin.html

ну а коцать символы в результатах java

[Удаление символов из строки java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779432/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-java)

или еще ишите на "java удалить символ из строки"

+думаю вам понадобится
= парсинг
= ру\en работа с символами
= знания другие

Comment: Нет, это из AuthenticationManagerBuilder (LdapUserDetails) получаю имя авторизованного пользователя, для дальнейшего применения.